# base64 decoding to UTF-8, one character not displaying correctly

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, base64, text-decoding

I am trying to decode a string from base64 to UTF-8 for an assignment.

Not having programmed Java for a while I am probably not using the most efficient method, however I managed to implement a function working 99% correctly.

Decoding the example string in Base64: **VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBBcnhhbiBzYW1wbGUgc3RyaW5nIHRoYXQgc2hvdWxkIGJlIGVhc2lseSBkZWNvZGVkIGZyb20gYmFzZTY0LiAgSXQgaW5jbHVkZXMgYSBudW1iZXIgb2YgVVRGOCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIHN1Y2ggYXMgdGhlIPEsIOksIOgsIOcgYW5kICYjOTYwOyBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzLg==**

Results in:
**This is an Arxan sample string that should be easily decoded from base64.      It includes a number of UTF8 characters such as the ñ, é, è, ç and &#960 characters.**

However, in the place of the &#960 should be the π symbol being outputted.

**Note that I removed the ; after &#960 in here as it seems Stackoverflow automatically corrected it to π**

I have tried many things such as creating a byte array and printing that, but still not working.

I am using Eclipse, can it be that just the output there displays incorrectly?

Does somebody have a suggestion to get this to work?

Thanks,
Vincent

Here is my code:

```
package base64;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Base64 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Input strings

        String base64 = "VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBBcnhhbiBzYW1wbGUgc3RyaW5nIHRoYXQgc2hvdWxkIGJlIGVhc2lseSBkZWNvZGVkIGZyb20gYmFzZTY0LiAgSXQgaW5jbHVkZXMgYSBudW1iZXIgb2YgVVRGOCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIHN1Y2ggYXMgdGhlIPEsIOksIOgsIOcgYW5kICYjOTYwOyBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzLg==";
        //String base64 = "YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3U=";
        String utf8 = "any carnal pleas";

        //Base64 to UTF8
        System.out.println("Base64 conversion to UTF8");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Input base64-string: " + base64);
        System.out.println("Output UTF8-string: " + stringFromBase64(base64));

        System.out.println();       

        //UTF8 to Base64
        System.out.println("UTF8 conversion to base64");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Input UTF8-string: " + utf8);
        System.out.println("Output base64-string: " + stringToBase64(utf8));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Pi is π");

    }

    public static String stringFromBase64(String base64) {
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

        int countPadding = countPadding(base64); //count number of padding symbols in source string
        //System.out.println("No of *=* in the input is : " + countPadding);
        //System.out.println(base64);       

        for(int i=0; i<(base64.length()-countPadding); i++)
        {       
            int base64Value = fromBase64(String.valueOf(base64.charAt(i))); //convert Base64 character to Int
            String base64Binary = Integer.toBinaryString(base64Value);  //convert Int to Binary string
            StringBuilder base64BinaryCopy = new StringBuilder(); //debugging

            if (base64Binary.length()<6) //adds required zeros to make 6 bit string
            {           

                for (int j=base64Binary.length();j<6;j++){
                    binary.append("0");
                    base64BinaryCopy.append("0"); //debugging
                }
                base64BinaryCopy.append(base64Binary); // debugging
            } else // debugging
            {
                base64BinaryCopy.append(base64Binary); //debugging

            } // debugging

            //System.out.println(base64.charAt(i) + " = " + base64Value + " = " + base64BinaryCopy); //debugging

            binary.append(base64Binary);            
        }

        //System.out.println(binary);
        //System.out.println(binary.length());


        StringBuilder utf8String = new StringBuilder();


        for (int bytenum=0;bytenum<(binary.length()/8);bytenum++) //parse string Byte-by-Byte
        {
            StringBuilder utf8Bit = new StringBuilder();
            for (int bitnum=0;bitnum<8;bitnum++){
                utf8Bit.append(binary.charAt(bitnum+(bytenum*8)));

            }

            char utf8Char = (char) Integer.parseInt(utf8Bit.toString(), 2); //Byte to utf8 char     
            utf8String.append(String.valueOf(utf8Char)); //utf8 char to string and append to final utf8-string  
            //System.out.println(utf8Bit + " = " + Integer.parseInt(utf8Bit.toString(), 2) + " = " + utf8Char + " = " + utf8String); //debugging
        }                   



        return utf8String.toString();   
    }


    public static String stringToBase64(String utf8) {
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        String paddingString = "";
        String paddingSymbols = "";

        for(int i=0; i<(utf8.length()); i++)
        {       
            int utf8Value = utf8.charAt(i); //convert utf8 character to Int
            String utf8Binary = Integer.toBinaryString(utf8Value);  //convert Int to Binary string
            StringBuilder utf8BinaryCopy = new StringBuilder(); //debugging

            if (utf8Binary.length()<8) //adds required zeros to make 8 bit string
            {           

                for (int j=utf8Binary.length();j<8;j++){
                    binary.append("0");
                    utf8BinaryCopy.append("0"); //debugging
                }
                utf8BinaryCopy.append(utf8Binary); // debugging
            } else // debugging
            {
                utf8BinaryCopy.append(utf8Binary); //debugging

            } // debugging

            //System.out.println(utf8.charAt(i) + " = " + utf8Value + " = " + utf8BinaryCopy);
            binary.append(utf8Binary);

        }

        if ((binary.length() % 6) == 2) {
            paddingString = "0000"; //add 4 padding zeroes
            paddingSymbols = "==";
        } else if ((binary.length() % 6) == 4) {
            paddingString = "00"; //add 2 padding zeroes
            paddingSymbols = "=";
        } 
        binary.append(paddingString); //add padding zeroes

        //System.out.println(binary);
        //System.out.println(binary.length());

        StringBuilder base64String = new StringBuilder();

        for (int bytenum=0;bytenum<(binary.length()/6);bytenum++) //parse string Byte-by-Byte per 6 bits
        {
            StringBuilder base64Bit = new StringBuilder();
            for (int bitnum=0;bitnum<6;bitnum++){
                base64Bit.append(binary.charAt(bitnum+(bytenum*6)));
            }
            int base64Int = Integer.parseInt(base64Bit.toString(), 2); //Byte to Int
            char base64Char = toBase64(base64Int); //Int to Base64 char 
            base64String.append(String.valueOf(base64Char)); //base64 char to string and append to final Base64-string  
            //System.out.println(base64Bit + " = " + base64Int + " = " + base64Char + " = " + base64String); //debugging
        }
        base64String.append(paddingSymbols); //add padding ==
        return base64String.toString(); 

    }

    public static char toBase64(int a) { //converts integer to corresponding base64 char
        String charBase64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        //charBase64 = new char[]{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N'};
        return charBase64.charAt(a);
    }

    public static int fromBase64(String x) { //converts base64 string to corresponding integer
        String charBase64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        return charBase64.indexOf(x);       
    }

    public static int countPadding(String countPadding) { //counts the number of padding symbols in base64 input string
        int index = countPadding.indexOf("=");
        int count = 0;
        while (index != -1) {
            count++;
            countPadding = countPadding.substring(index + 1);
            index = countPadding.indexOf("=");
        }
        return count;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncomment your last debug statement in stringFromBase64 (the one in the "for (int bytenum=0;" ).  You'll find output that shows that the characters "&","#","9","6","0" are individually output.  This means the encoded string contains those characters, not the pi symbol.

Comment: To encode/decode UTF8 string correctly, you may have to first convert UTF8 string to byte array and work from there.

Comment: Thanks all. I read the suggestion about a byte array somewhere but couldn't get it to work properly. If you have any suggestions that would be great. How can I convert my string that consists of bits to a byte array?

Comment: I have a Base64 implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/dragon66/0bbb076b6c21202ea958) about 15 years old which is intended to read write in UTF-8 encoding. It doesn't seem to work in all cases though. Just for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 is a character encoding that transforms a given char to 1, 2 or more bytes. Your code assumes that each byte should be transformed to a character. That works fine for ASCII characters such as a, b, c that are indeed transformed to a single byte by UTF8, but it doesn't work for characters like PI, which are transformed to a multi-byte sequence.

Your algorithm is awfully inefficient, and I would just ditch it and use a ready-to-use ecnoder/decoder. The JDK 8 [comes with one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) and [commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) also do. Your code should be as simple as

```
String base64EncodedByteArray = "....";
byte[] decodedByteArray = decoder.decode(base64EncodedByteArray);
String asString = new String(decodedByteArray, StandardCharSets.UTF_8);
```

or, for the other direction:

```
String someString = "VGhpcyBpcyBhb...";
byte[] asByteArray = someString.getBytes(StandardCharSets.UTF_8);
String base64EncodedByteArray = encoder.encode(asBytArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's good to know that UTF8 characters can consist of multiple bytes, I am not sure though how to solve that at this point.

True my code is very inefficient. This is an assignment I was asked to do, and on purpose I did not look at existing solutions (of which I knew they existed) before trying to implement this as it was important I did it myself. I have not programmed for several years, hence the clumsy solution :)

Although if you may have any quick tips to make the code more efficient this would be useful (without using the standard functions).

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: The obvious thing to change is to stop representing a byte as a String of 8 characters '1' and '0', but as a primitive `byte`.